# how to post on fb wall using an edit text instead of fb post to wall dialog?

Tags: android, facebook

I am taking an edit box and button in my app to post status on Facebook. I don't want to use a Facebook Dialog for post status. Instead I want that the status I am writing in my edit box is posted on Facebook when I click on the button. I am using this code:

```
public class PostToWallActivity extends Activity{
    public static final String APP_ID = "1****************";
    private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        postTowallButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.postTowall_btn);
        postTowallButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                postTowall();
            }
        });
    }

    private void postTowall() {
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
            }
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                String sh = null;
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("caption", sh);
                mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, 
                    "POST", new WallPostListener(), null);
                mRunOnUi.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(LogoutActivity.this, "Posted to Facebook",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            public void onCancel() {
            }
        });            
    }

    public class WallPostListener implements RequestListener {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Got response: " + response);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is the above code not working? Or is it working but showing the dialog? And you want to replace this? Have a closer look into the Github Android SDK. Maybe the following is what you are looking for

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/search?q=Request.newPostRequest&type=Code

Answer (score 0):

You are using a deprecated version of the Facebook SDK, please update to the latest version.

It sounds like you want to post a status on the user's behalf, which will require your app to ask for "publish_actions" permissions from the user, and using the Graph API to post.

Have a look at the HelloFacebook sample application that ships with the latest version of the SDK. It shows you how to post a status update on the user's behalf.

Comment: not on user's behalf.i just want an edit text box in my app and the comment which user writes in it should post on fb wall using post button.

Comment: You can't do that. Facebook does not allow you to preemptively set the text for a status update. The only way to do it is to ask the user for publish_actions permissions, and use the Graph API to create a post on the user's behalf.